# How to var[0].var1[0] in Hugo template?

Tags: hugo, go-templates

I can only do `(index .var 0).var1` but my var1 is also an array, how do I select it's index?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Hugo index function](https://gohugo.io/functions/index-function/):

> Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the following arguments.
>
> Thus “`index x 1 2 3`” is, in Go syntax, `x[1][2][3]`.
> Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array.

In your case, do check if this would be enough (change the second '0' by the index you want to access within `var1`.

```
index .var 0 0
```

Comment: I did {{ (index .var 0 0).var1}} but it does not work. Is that what you ment?

Comment: No, I meant only `index .car 0 0`, no need for var1 anymore

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. What I'm trying to get is var[0].var1[0].Text

Comment: Is var1 stored in the first index of var0?

Comment: .Context contains an array of section and section is an array of group. In golang template I basically have to do Context.Section[].Group[].Property

Comment: It doesn't. It just gives me a blank page

Comment: And I don't suppose that `index (index .var 0).var1 0` would work?

Comment: I tried that too and it does not work unfortunately, I guess I'm gonna handle it on the backend first to make templating easier.

Comment: @StormAsdg Agreed. Don't hesitate to post an answer here (you can accept your own answer). Also consider https://discourse.gohugo.io/: maybe someone can help there.